# OSMNx Extracting blocks from point and save coordinates of corners of each block

Tags: python, osmnx

I am playing with OSMNx and I would like to extract street blocks,

I have this code which should display the blocks

```
import osmnx as ox
import geopandas as gpd
import shapely
from shapely.geometry import Polygon
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np


point = (50.090988, 14.425114)

streets_graph = ox.graph_from_point(point, distance=500, network_type='drive')
streets_graph = ox.project_graph(streets_graph)

streets = ox.save_load.graph_to_gdfs(streets_graph, nodes=False, edges=True,
                                     node_geometry=False, fill_edge_geometry=True)

point = streets.unary_union.centroid

polygons = shapely.ops.polygonize(intersections.geometry)
polygons = gpd.GeoSeries(polygons)
target = polygons.loc[polygons.contains(point)]
```

This is how the area near the point looks like on Google maps:
This is what I get:
[image]

[image]

Then I tried to isolate the intersections which I would then use to create the polygons I need

```py
intersections = ox.clean_intersections(streets_graph, tolerance=15, dead_ends=False)

gdf = gpd.GeoDataFrame(geometry=intersections)
gdf.crs = streets_graph.graph['crs']
gdf_projected = ox.project_gdf(gdf, to_latlong=True)
polygons.plot()
plt.show()
```

And I got something more realistic:

[image]

And my question is:

How can I connect those intersections in order to get these polygons as shown on the first image from google maps AND (this is the most important part for me: How to get coordinates of each polygon edge?

Or at least, how can I fix the drawings that the 2nd picture would resemble first picture?